# What are the most prestigious photography awards worldwide?

Tags: photographer

When I hear about "award-winning" photographers it is always interesting to know what awards have they won. Is there a list of most prestigious international photography awards? Are there top awards for beginners, students etc?

Answer (score 3):

I would say it depends on what you are photographing. If you take [Joe Buissink](http://www.joebuissink.com/) for example, he is a wedding photographer and thus the awards tend to have wedding photography as its topic.

A list could be [this one on wp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Photography_awards). Or [The Huge List of International Photography Awards and Competitions](http://fotografiamagazine.com/photography-awards-competitions/)

Answer (score 0):

Really interesting question.

I just would add that some awards could be local competitions, probably one organized by the culture department of your city or probably it is nationwide.

Some could be organized by a magazine or a camera brand.

The more recognized magazine or the more coverage the brand make to the competition, the better.

Of course, there are many categories, there are political magazines, journalists, travel, real estate, commercial photography, fashion, arts, etc. So you probably would like to find a suitable category to find specific awards.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a list of most prestigious international photography awards?

Sure there are lots. How authoritative they are, I have no idea. :)

- [The Most Prestigious International Photo Awards](https://contrastly.com/the-most-prestigious-international-photography-awards/)
- [Top 10 Photography Awards to Get You Noticed](https://idesigni.co.uk/blog/top-photography-awards/)
- [The Best Photography Contests and Prizes in 2018](https://www.format.com/magazine/resources/photography/best-photography-contest-prizes-2016)
- [Top Photography Contest Websites](https://photographyspark.com/photo-contest-website-list/)
- [The 10 best photography competitions to enter this Autumn](http://www.bjp-online.com/2017/11/10-best-competitions-enter-this-autumn/)
- Wikipedia's [category of Photography Awards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Photography_awards)

With most of these lists, there are a few candidates that pop up over and over again, such as IPA (International Photography Award), Sony's World Photography Awards, and the National Geographic Photo Contest.

But I don't think most of them even mentions the Pulitzer for Feature Photography. :) So, as with all "top ten" lists, prestige depends on the the viewer. It's why we've got Saturn awards as well as the Oscars.